# Android Studio's Properties Window Missing

Tags: android, android-studio

I have no idea where the properties window went. As you can see it should be under Component Tree, but it is not and there is a gray area to the right of it. any ideas?[image]

Comment: Try opening it by clicking the grey rectangle at the very bottom left hand of the screen, that should open up a context menu

Comment: check if you can you compile a project and run

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because of the `Component Tree's` size which is too much.

**See, before increasing the size:**

[image]

**After that:**

[image]

**Try to decrease the size with clicking and holding the click from left side of that panel to right.**

This will solve the problem.

Comment: Yw, anytime! Goodluck!

Answer (score 3):

Reduce the size of the Component tree panel will solve your problem.

For a better solution, you can click on panel option, In editor mode, Left.
And restart and change position of the panel to Right. (solve the problem on my computer). This problem is only present when the properties panel is attach to the right sidebar

Answer (score 3):

An updated answer for Android Studio 3.5.3:

[Android Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6jY5.png)

1) Open a layout file such as the default "activity_main.xml" in the app/res/layout folder (yellow oval).

2) Click on Design view (green oval).

3) If the Attributes window is closed, click on its tab to open it (red oval).

4) If the Attributes pane says "No component selected" click on an element such as the TextView.  The attributes of that element should now be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

This worked

Select  **design view** from layout editor. [image]

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem go to VIEW - Tool Windows - Properties. then it would pop back up.

Answer (score 0):

Close the IDE and open again, this works for me.

PD: the classic solution.

Answer (score -2):

WINDOWS operating system only:

1. first is you download android studio from here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

2. When youre done, WinRAR file will appear on the bottom left of your screen;
3. Create an empty folder and place it on desktop or to any other location you want to choose;
4. Extract the WinRAR to the folder you created;
5. When you're done, open the folder and go to the "bin" subfolder;
6. look for studio64.exe file  if you're running on a 64bit Windows;
7. if you're running a 64 bit JAVA, make sure that you're 64bit window is also properly set to a 64 bit in the environment variable; you will see this if you open system properties window and at the bottom part of that window you will see "environment variables;" make sure that it is set for 64 bit because mine was set for 32 bit and I manually changed it to 64 bit and it solved the problem; if there's a misalignment between your JAVA environment and your 64bit Window, JAVA will not run properly.

by the way you can also directly search for the "environment variable" in the seach window by clicking the search icon. My search icon is located on the bottom left of my screen (mine is windows 10)

8. After doing #7, you are now set; double click the studio64.exe and follow the installation guide. You should do just fine like I did.
9. I hope this solves this glitch. Goodluck.

[image]

[image]