# How can I access Android Studio Properties Window?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I've just installed Android Studio and I have a hard time finding where the Properties window is. From what I can see online it should be right under ConstraintLayout - Component Tree.

Can you guys please help me out?

My interface layout:

[image: My interface layout]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio's Properties Window Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831085/android-studios-properties-window-missing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the Component Tree's size which is too much.

Reduce the size of the Component tree panel will solve your problem.

For a better solution, you can click on panel option, In editor mode, Left. And restart and change position of the panel to Right. (solve the problem on my computer). This problem is only present when the properties panel is attach to the right sidebar