# Properties panel is missing in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio

There is no "Properties" panel under the Component Tree section.

This thread has not resolved my issue:
[Android Studio's Properties Window Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831085/android-studios-properties-window-missing/34831173)

How to make the "Properties" panel visible?

I'm running Android Studio 3.0.1 on Fedora 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with Android Studio 3.0.1, all the fields from the Properties panel can now be found under the Attributes section, particularly by clicking "View all attributes".